# How should I run drain line from water softner to sewer cleanout -- located outside?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, water-softener

I need to run a drain line from a water softner to a sewer cleanout. The water softner and cleanout are located outside and right next to each other. The builder designed it so a water softner could be added later.

How should I run a drain line off the sewer line to the water softner? The sewer cleanout inside the green housing has a recessed 3" abs plug.

Something like a sanitary tee > p-trap > air gap > drain line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Something like a sanitary tee > p-trap > air gap > drain line.`

Yup, that part's good. Thinking is sound.

The fact that you now have to run a vent line from that location to above the roofline (possibly further depending on window locations, lower story and upper story roofs, etc) or have a stinky sewer vent **right there** is less than ideal. I guess you could try an Air Admittance Valve / Mechanical Vent. I hate the things for lack of reliability, but it's a tradeoff in this situation.